# Anybody see this kind of DC restorer or clamper, would you like to give out the detailed solution for the output waveform

Tags: diodes

In the following circuit as shown in Fig-1, assume that the diode is ideal and has a forward voltage of 0.7V. Given RC>>T, Sketch accurately the output waveform for the circuit. I have simulated the circuit with different group of R and C as shown in Fig-2. The interesting thing is that once I keep the two R same , the output( peak value) is almost same, or 8V as shown in Fig-3.  can anyone tell me why the input waveform is shifted down with around 2V?  really appreciate that .
[image]

Some symbols are added into Fig-1-x to understand the Eq.2 given out by Jonk.
[image: Fig-1-x]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7y8zH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Based on the solution provided by Jonk, here I give my calculation details:
Eq.2 is derived from Eq.1. Am I right? @Jonk
[image]

Here is the derivation details of Vc as below: 
[image]

What about the solution for Vo in Fig.6?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzH47A.png)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this pretty easily. Once steady-state arrives, you know that the currents flowing in and out must be the same. Early on, the voltage across the capacitor is zero. But the capacitor ***must*** acquire a mean voltage across it that results in equal currents flowing in one direction matching the currents flowing in the opposite direction when it is in steady-state.

So, it follows that:

$$\frac1{\pi}\int_0^\pi \frac{V_0\operatorname{sin}\theta-V_\text{D}+V_\text{C}}{R_2}\:\text{d}\theta+\frac1{\pi}\int_0^\pi \frac{V_0\operatorname{sin}\theta+V_\text{C}}{R_1}\:\text{d}\theta+\frac1{\pi}\int_0^\pi \frac{-V_0\operatorname{sin}\theta+V_\text{C}}{R_1}\:\text{d}\theta=0\:\text{A}$$

This solves out as:

$$V_\text{C}=\frac{V_\text{D}-\frac{2\cdot V_0}{\pi}}{1+2\frac{R_2}{R_1}}$$

Given the low currents in the diode, indicated by \$R_1=R_2=100\:\text{k}\Omega\$, I might estimate \$V_\text{D}\approx 400\:\text{mV}\$. From this, I find that \$V_\text{C}\approx -1.989\:\text{V}\$. Which explains the approximate \$2\:\text{V}\$ shift in your output.

Please note that the above assumes that the diode's conduction angle is equal to the angle when it doesn't conduct. This is "mostly true" when \$R_1\approx R_2\$. But if you change the value of \$R_2\$ so that the conduction angle changes significantly, the above formula isn't correct. (I assumed a simplification to get an easy result.)

But since you only asked to explain the result you have, the above is enough.

Comment: Thank you for your nice solution, Jonk. Based on your solution I edited my question and add your solution and some new questions into it.  in Fig-6, I changed the value of R1=two times of R2 and add another diode. based on your comment, if the values of R1 and R2 are different, the conduction angle of the diode changes significantly. would you like to show me  how the difference in terms of the resistors's values affects the output Vo through Fig-6? thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

> This positive clamp is not a very effective positive clamp due to the excessive high diode  R added in series.

Negative clamps are more common using a peak pulse detector that creates a 1 shot to short out the input capacitor to 0V   or a very short duration with a low Rce transistor or a low RdsOn FET. This design is unstable for a positive clamp due to the low R Ratio = 1 instead of > 100:1.

This is NOT  how to design a DC restorer.  The conducting switch being a FET, BJT, Analog switch or diode must be low Resistance compared to the load R of 100k so that positive peak is as close to 0V as possible.

The decay of C1*R=Tau must also acceptable over a time interval of T=1/f.